# How to copy content of MediaWiki into XML

Tags: mediawiki

We have a MediaWiki server that we need to migrate to SharePoint. However, is that possible to somehow copy the content of MediaWiki into XML so that later we could apply that content into out SharePoint site?

Is the MediaWiki accessible or is there a technology that could copy its sites in a corresponding structure into an external content holder, such as XML file?

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[dumpBackup.php](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:DumpBackup.php) exports your wiki in XML format.

It doesn't export your file; you probably want to keep a copy of your file directory.